# PDO:: fetch_assoc and fetch_object difference & when best to use

Tags: php, pdo

I've taken a look around and I can't seem to find any good threads or explanations with examples on when to use or not use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or `PDO:: FETCH_OBJECT` I always use the `ASSOC` when fetching username etc but when would be appropriate to use object over it? or vice versa. I have checked the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) but I'm still struggling to wrap my head around it, if someone could provide an explanation with examples I'd appreciate it so much

Thank you

Comment: There is no basic difference. It is really up to you whether you like your rows to be  returned as Objects or Arrays. Which do you prefer, which makes most sense in your app.

Comment: Depends on what you want to use. In general I go for object notation simply because the `$object->property` is easier to type and more readable than `$array['key']`.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: One use-case for fetching as an object is that you can specify what class you want PDO to instantiate and populate with data. So if you require that your data be returned as a result set of specific objects (maybe to enforce specific behaviour or to adhere to an interface) you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, if you needed the object syntax you would know it! Basically, in a situation where you *want* to treat the rows in your database as objects with attributes, the `fetch_object` method provides you with a convenient way to create them.

Now why would you want to? It's a simple form of "object-relational mapping", a common way of working with data that's moved in and out of a database. Let's start from the other end: Suppose you already have some objects with attributes, and you want to persist them to a database. You would then declare a table to hold the object instances, with a column for each attribute, and later you read the objects back in with this method.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks! upvoted and accepted! think my question ban got reinstated though rippp see you in 6 monthsss:D

Comment: To add on to *If you already have some objects with attributes*, if the object is instantiated, as opposed to a "class" with declared properties. You would typically want to use `PDOStatement::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $object)`, followed by `PDOStatement::fetch()`.  By default `fetch_object`  is an alternative syntax for `PDOStatement::fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` or `PDOStatement::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'stdClass')` which produces an anonymous object with the database column names as properties.

Comment: Question ban? I'm surprised, this is not such a terrible question... Well, I hope you get out of it sooner!

Comment: @fyrye, thanks for the code details! (The question was conceptual, so I don't think code is required in the answer, but it's appreciated :-)). To be clear, what my answer describes is a situation where you have objects _with data,_ you write them out to a database, and then at some later point, in a later program, you fetch the data from the database and create new objects to hold it.

Comment: Since the OP wanted to know when it is more appropriate to use `FETCH_OBJ` as opposed to `FETCH_ASSOC` with examples. It is more so opinionated than conceptual, as there is no one right answer, outside of personal preference or app specific requirements that were not provided. Since `FETCH_OBJ` will always only produce an anonymous object, and this mentions reading the column data back in as object attributes, I determined the distinction between a class, an object, `FETCH_OBJ`, `fetch_object()` and `fetch_object('Class')` needed to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

By default pdo fetch and fecthAll allow using the 2 way assoc and object.
When your column name has space or another caractere outside ascii and then we should use assoc instead object `$row['the name'];` not `$row->the name` (This cause arror).
Or like `$row->colômn // cause error`.
I think that's the reason we should use

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't really make sense. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Pascal, I _do_ see what you are saying: There are cases where the object syntax cannot be used. So far, so good, you are right. But the OP's question is, when/why would one _want_ to use the object syntax?

Comment: @alexis the OP wants to know when it is more appropriate to use one instead of the other: *when would be appropriate to use object over it? or vice versa*. This provides a use-case of when not use `FETCH_OBJ`.

Comment: For clarification, by default, `PDOStatement::fetch()` and `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` uses `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` (default `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`) which returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number. ie `[0 => 'value', 'column_name' => 'value']`